# Filtering Flink datastream to optional sub-object in Scala

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using Flink in Scala to route and transform Protobuf events (using scalapb) in our analytics pipeline. I have a datastream of "PlayStreams" with this schema:

```
message PlayStream {
  optional PlayerEvent player_event = 1;
  optional BlockAccountIPEvent block_account_ip_event = 2;
}
```

The resulting generated case class has a `playerEvent` member of type signature `Option[PlayerEvent]`.

I want to transform the datastream into just PlayerEvents, filtering out any that do not have them. I'm new to Scala, so I'm not sure how to do this idiomatically. What I have currently works fine:

```
   // in main()
   getDataStream(name, env, config.get("KafkaSource"))
      .keyBy[String](PlayStreamFunctions.key(_))
      .map{ _.getPlayerEvent }
      .filter(filterDefaultPlayerEvents(_))


  def filterDefaultPlayerEvents(playerEvent: PlayerEvent): Boolean = {
    playerEvent match {
      case PlayerEvent.defaultInstance => false
      case _ => true
    }
  }
```

This works because `getPlayerEvent` in the generated class is just `playerEvent.getOrElse(PlayerEvent.defaultInstance)`, and we don't use the default instance for anything. However, It feels weird creating a bunch of references to the defaultInstance only to immediately filter them out in the next step. Is there a way avoid that, that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to clarify that I scoped this question under Flink since all the map functions are Flink-specific implementations. I realized `flatMap` was available and, given that [map operations are more idiomatic than pattern matching for Options](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html), I went with this implementation:

```
  getDataStream(name, env, config.get("KafkaSource"))
      .keyBy[String](PlayStreamFunctions.key(_))
      .flatMap{ _.playerEvent.toList }
      .flatMap(toFlatPlayerEvent(_))
```

since `toList` returns an empty list if the Option doesn't exist, or a unary list with the value if it does, flat mapping across them solves my problem.